Running a request from postman testscript of another request
Requirement:There are 2 requests, request A and request B. I need to run Request A when a condition specified in the test script of Request B is attained in POSTMAN. I used the below code, but while running, in the console I am getting "Status" : "Unauthorized".
The authorization method is bearer token and i have put the token in the collection authorization tab. In the request I have chosen the Inherit from parent. But I am not sure how or where to put the authorization details while running the request from the Test script.
Please let me know the solution.
var request = {
method: 'POST',
url: 'https://', // Replace with your failure endpoint URL
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept':'application/json',
'Authorization':'Bearer 324ghvvj23vhvhjvhjvjhvjhvhjvj'
// Add any additional headers as needed
},
};
// Send the request
pm.sendRequest(request, function (err, res) {
if (err) {
console.error(err);
return;
}
console.log('Request sent successfully:', res);
});

Have you tried using header and not headers in the async request?

I am confuse on your explanation what kind of function for request A and B? Example B is getting access token A is call API with using access token. Why run first request B? In tests tab of B, pick-up access token, assign it to collection variable and run A if success to get it, If not skip to run A. correct? Also A will use the token at its header with Bearer token. Please make a clear your question.
